# PHP MySql Pricing With Three Season Date Range With Season Overlaps

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date, date-range

I hope I can explain this correctly, I'm using PHP with a MySql DB. I live in NZ so the seasons below may seem odd. My real tables have a more columns but these columns are what I think are needed to explain my dilemma.

I have a DB table for and called '**customer**'

| id | name | address | booking_start_date | booking_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 8 Some Road | 2021-12-22 | 2022-07-31 |
| 2 | Susan | 44 Another RD | 2021-07-01 | 2021-10-26 |

another DB table for & called '**caravan**'

| id_cvn | name_cvn | image_cvn | rego_cvn | bond_cvn | low_season_price | mid_season_price | peak_season_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 Birth | caddie.jpg | GD3313 | 1000 | 75 | 90 | 110 |
| 2 | 2 Birth | gipsy.jpg | FH887 | 1000 | 55 | 70 | 90 |

& I have this DB table called '**season_switch**'

| id | title | title_value | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Low | 1 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-07-31 |
| 2 | Mid | 2 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-11-30 |
| 3 | Peak | 3 | 2021-12-01 | 2022-03-31 |

I want to have 3 seasons(at present) **Jan-Apr** then **May-Aug** then **Sep-Dec** (I want this to be dynamic so it could possibly change to a week before to a week after each season)

I had a php page that calculated the prices & worked fine & worked off the season value 1, 2, or 3 when **I used to have it in the caravan table**. I realized this didn't work correctly as the site owner would set the season to 1,2 or 3 for each caravan & update it as required (when the seasons changed) but the customer might for example book the caravan in the future that is partly in **Low season** (winter) and partly in **Mid Season** (spring to summer) or in fact any overlapping seasons/dates, so the customers price would be incorrect as it was calculating what was set not what the customer is choosing.

This is where I'm stuck & my explanation may get lost, I am using a while loop (is this the best way) to get the seasons start & end dates into an array of dates & count them up & I thought the best way was to create the table **season_switch** to compare the booked customer dates with.

1. The dates in season_switch are like **2021-04-01** but this would only need months & days I presume as the year will be irrelevant?
2. How do I compare/calculate the days in one season at the price for those days in that season (whatever season it may end up being) to then add up the days in the overlapping season with the price for that season?

Below are the loops I'm using at present(not sure if it's the correct way to do it). I used some code with +1day (I had this for my datepickers & it's fine there) but can't seem to successfully remove it, so seasons start a day late.

The for loop finds the 2 test dates but I'm not sure how to do that as an array of the customers booked dates (they will be array of all dates between start & end) & how to match to seasons, count then add up the different season prices. In the test dates in the for loop they would start in peak & end in low (I hope this somehow makes sense).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM season_switch ORDER BY 'id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      
        $season_title = $row["title"];
        $season_value = $row["title_value"];
        $season_start_date = $row["start_date"];
        $season_end_date = $row["end_date"];
        
        echo $season_title.'<BR>';
        
        echo '<BR>';
        while (strtotime($season_start_date) <= strtotime($season_end_date)) {
            $date_entry[] =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($season_start_date));
            $season_start_date = date ("D, d-M-Y", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($season_start_date)));

            echo '<div style="color:blue;">'.$season_start_date.'</div>';
        }   
          
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    foreach( $date_entry as $DBrow )
    {

        $start = "2021-03-03";
        $end = "2021-05-06";
        
        if( ( $start == $DBrow ) or ( $end == $DBrow ) )
        {
            echo '<H2 style="color:red">'."Duplicate Date Found! ".$DBrow.'</H2>';
            
        }else{    
            echo '<H2 style="color:black">'."No Date Found! ".$DBrow.'</H2>';
        }
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////
}else{
    echo "0 results";
}
```